# Processing an uploaded file using Django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I'm attempting to process an uploaded CSV file using Django. The main logic of how I go about doing this is expressed in both the `models.py` and `views.py` scripts. Once I've uploaded the file, I'm unable to process any of the content (in my `views.py`). Here are the two scripts, but if there's any more information I can provide, I'd be happy to.

In my `models.py` file, I have two classes, one for the document itself, and the other class for the fields in the file.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

import os

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')

class DocumentEntry(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="TEST")
```

Next, in my `views.py` I get the file that was uploaded via the `request.FILES['docfile']` and pass it to the `handle_files()` function. However, when I try to loop through the reader, I'm unable to access any of the elements in the file that was uploaded.

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

import csv

from .models import Document, DocumentEntry
from .forms import UploadFileForm


def process_file(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            handle_files(request.FILES['docfile'])

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('process_files'))
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(
        request,
        'upload/process_files.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form}
    )


def handle_files(csv_file):

    newdoc = Document(docfile=csv_file)
    newdoc.save()

    reader = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file))
    for row in reader:
        field = row['field']
        entry = DocumentEntry(document=newdoc, field=field)
        entry.save()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

Here is full example of handler function:

```
def handle_files(csv_file):

   newdoc = Document(docfile=csv_file)
   newdoc.save()

   with open(newdoc.docfile.name) as f:
      reader = csv.DictReader(f)
      for row in reader:
         field = row['field']
         entry = DocumentEntry(document=newdoc, field=field)
         entry.save()
```

Comment: Any ideas on how I would get the name? I can create a helper function in ```models.py``` to return the filename, but of course, I wouldn't be able to access that function when creating an object.

Comment: I have updated my answer for example of file name function. Seems we also need to use read() from file object.

Comment: Here is what information you can get from uploaded file:
file = request.FILES['filename']
file.name           # Gives name
file.content_type   # Gives Content type text/html etc
file.size           # Gives file's size in byte
file.read()         # Reads file

Comment: Thanks Gagik, what is ```File``` in your example where ```newdoc = Document(docfile=File(csv_file.read(), name=csc_file.name))```

Comment: Oh sorry, I had to point it. It is: from django.core.files.base import  File

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks for that. Hmm, I'm now receiving a ```'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'``` error. I tried removing the ```.read()``` and also the ```open``` when I define the ```reader```, but still no luck there either. Any thoughts?

Comment: I re-read the docs from django documentation and cvs and seems I was wrong django FileField handles the uploaded file.  I have updated with new example, where I try to open the file from Documet model just was created. if that doesn't work I don't have other clue :(

Answer (score 1):

[open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) expects the path to the file, not the actual file data, which is contained in `request.FILES['docfile']`.

Replace:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file))
```

with:

```
import io
io_file = io.TextIOWrapper(csv_file.file)
reader = csv.DictReader(io_file)
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas, although this appears to give me the following error: ```iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)```

Comment: @VincentRusso True, updated my answer with the proper fix.

Comment: thanks again, but it seems that now the program does not enter the ```for row in reader:``` loop. Indeed, when I check ```print(list(reader))```, the list is empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check if `csv_file.file` is empty too. That would be very odd.

Comment: Yeah it is, and I have no idea why that would be the case. It may be because I'm passing the ```request.FILES['docfile']``` to the ```handle_files(csv_file)``` function. It seems when I just try to do what you suggested directly after ```if form.is_valid()```, I get the error: ```'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 12588: character maps to <undefined>```

Comment: Thing is that `request.FILES['docfile']` contains an instance of `UploadedFile` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile), so `request.FILES['docfile'].file` should contain the actual file data. The fact that it doesn't contain anything at all makes me wonder if the problem wouldn't be somewhere else...

Comment: True. My starting point for this project was found here: https://github.com/axelpale/minimal-django-file-upload-example/tree/master/src/for_django_1-9/myproject. It's pretty minimal, and I'm not sure where else I would be going wrong or where else the problem would even be located.